# Best approach to create a text classification model with two inputs?

Tags: keras, nlp, text-classification

I'm looking to train a model with two text inputs (sentences) and a binary classification. Essentially, for 2 given sentences, are they paraphrases or not.

I want to use the Microsoft research Paraphrase Detection dataset as I feel this would be a good place to start.

What would be the best approach to do this?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my naïvete.

Answer (score 1):

All current pre-trained Transformers (BERT, RoBERTa, ...) can take two sentences as an input, simply by concatenating the sentences and separating them by a special token. You can then finetune the model on the paraphrase dataset.

The Microsoft Research Parallel Corpus is part of the [GLUE benchmark](https://gluebenchmark.com/leaderboard) for sentence representation evaluation. It has a public leaderboard, so you can have a look and get an idea, how the best models look like.